# Correspondence table between regional spatial units from NUTS and GADM

Tags: spatial

The NUTS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomenclature_of_Territorial_Units_for_Statistics) divides countries into regions.

So does the GADM (https://gadm.org/).

Is there any publicly available correspondence table that allows for an (approximate) matching between the two?

Comment: This is unhelpful, but https://data.apps.fao.org/catalog/dataset/gadm-codes lists the codes GADM uses and I'm sure you already have NUTS2021.xlsx -- there is occasional match between GID_3 (or GID_2) in GADM being something like "BEL.2.5.5_1" and the entry in NUTS2021.xlsx being almost the undotted version with the _1 removed, in this case: BE255. Note, however, NUTS uses "BE" and GADM uses "BEL", so you'll have to play around with this.